# non sequential SQL partitioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, partitioning

> Blockquote

All,

I am trying to partition a set of data but I don't want my partitions to be "sequential".

Traditionally by partitioning by ID and then by sale stage I get this. Sequential partitioning.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  ID,  sale stage ORDER BY  Converge, modified date desc)

ID               sale stage      modified date      partition
01_AAI_73133    Closed Lost        5/1/2015             1
01_AAI_73133    Closed Lost        4/26/2015            2
01_AAI_73133    Closed Lost        4/20/2015            3
01_AAI_73133    Locked and Loaded  4/5/2015             1
01_AAI_73133    Locked and Loaded  3/29/2015            2
01_AAI_73133    Pitching           3/7/2015             1
01_AAI_73133    Pitching           2/14/2015            2
01_AAI_73133    Pitching           2/1/2015             3
01_AAI_73134    Pitching           1/20/2015            4
```

What I actually want is this

```
ID               sale stage      modified date      partition
01_AAI_73133    Closed Lost        5/1/2015             1
01_AAI_73133    Closed Lost        4/26/2015            1
01_AAI_73133    Closed Lost        4/20/2015            1
01_AAI_73133    Locked and Loaded  4/5/2015             2
01_AAI_73133    Locked and Loaded  3/29/2015            2
01_AAI_73133    Pitching           3/7/2015             3
01_AAI_73133    Pitching           2/14/2015            3
01_AAI_73133    Pitching           2/1/2015             3
01_AAI_73134    Pitching           1/20/2015            3
```

Does anyone have a idea how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Politank-Z I am using MSSQL 2012

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `dense_rank()`:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID, salestage)
```

If you are trying to order by the maximum date for each id and sale stage, then you might need a subquery:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by maxmd, id, salestate)
from (select . . .,
             MAX(ModifiedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, salestage) as maxmd
      from . . .
     ) t;
```

Comment: I think we are on the right track with dense rank but its not restarting the rank when we get to a new ID. for example 01_AAI_73133/ 111223333 and then for the nex id of 01_AAI_73145/ 11123334444. does that make sense?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.  ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY  ID  ORDER BY  SALESTAGE)  Thank you!